# Generate random integer key based on two columns from databse

Tags: java, etl, informatica, masking

I have a requirement where I need to generate a unique number as a surrogate key based on my composite primary key.

For example

```
 col1 col2
 1    abc
 1    xyz
 2    wrt
 3    yuy
```

generate the key (any random unique number should be created by based on column1 and column2 )
Key should be in integer format
the key should be unique for `col1` and `col2` pair
This I have to achieve in informatica
I do not want to use a sequence generator (I do not want to generate the key based      on row like sequence rather it should be generated based on my composite key)
I do not want to use MD5 as I need only numeric value.

Looking forward to any helpful answers

Thanks in avance

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: Side note: The MD5 algorithm **does** generate an integer. It's often written in hexadecimal notation but still an integer none the less.